# Website own PHPMyAdmin

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

How to stop a client to access my databases if he uploads his own PHPMyAdmin in his website.

We have a IIS server where user uploads there website through FTP and suddenly one user upload his project and in his directory we found PHPMyAdmin folder too so from that position he can access our all databases.

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because he installs PHPMyAdmin doesn't mean he can access all your databases. He still can only access his own databases (the one on your MySQL database where he has access credentials for and possibly remote ones on other machines).

Comment: But we also have to stop him to access his own DB from this

Comment: Why? If it is his own DB, he has the right to access it, don't you think?

Comment: Because we have a different situation if he wants to access his own DB he has to come through vpn machine then through this vpn connects to DB server this is separate process thats why we want to stop it from the website

Comment: @Prince If you want to both prohibit the users from utilizing the website to administer their databases. And allow the users to wholly administer the website. While enforcing access policies... You might want to redesign your set-up, segregate your environment a bit more.

Comment: which type of redesign please explain

Comment: Just offer PHPMyAdmin as a service for your users and put it into a HTTPS host. This spares your users the pain of having to setup a VPN to access their databases.